# Can we use the Facebook Comment Box plugin to display comments of an FB post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We scrape *starred* Facebook posts on our FB page via the API and save them in our DB. Now we want to show those starred posts on our site and have a comment functionality.

The problem is that we need this to be bi-directional, so a comment made on FB shows up on our site and vice versa.

I tried setting the data-href to the unique URL of the Facebook post (http://facebook.com/{PageName}/posts/{PostId}) but that doesn't work (different comments on the FB post page and on our version of the post). Also tried combinations of http, https, www, PageId or PageName.

Of course we could get it through the API but that wouldn't be optional as our site has no Facebook login functionality and we'd prefer users to post without having to authorize anything.

```
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
            <h1>Kommentare</h1>
            <div class="fb-comments"
                 data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151631557213553" 
                 data-width="470"></div>
```

Comment: Including the relevant code in your post makes it more likely someone will be able to help you, as it will give them a better idea of what exactly you are doing. Thanks!

Comment: Added, though I do not know how pure FB boilerplate code will help. People who do not know about the comment box plugin won't be able to help anyway.

Comment: There is no connection between comments on facebook.com and comments made via the comments plugin (even if you give an FB URL as data-href). What you want is not possible.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thank you. If you posted this as answer it'd be the approved one :)